# Using database to store Basic Auth credentials

Tags: mysql, apache, authentication, basic-authentication

Im trying to set up basic authentication on my website but instead of using a .htpasswd file to store credentials im trying to use a database using mod_authn_dbd - i have followed this guide: https://blog.froese.org/2014/06/13/authn-dbd-mysql-ubuntu-trusty/

But having some issues with the connection to the database. 
So i have my lamp stack(using ScotchBox) set up with a table called users to store the credentials.

My conf file looks like so:

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=127.0.0.1,user=vagrant,pass=PASSWORD"
DBDMin  2
DBDKeep 4
DBDMax  10
DBDExptime 300
```

My vhost looks like:

```
DBDParams "dbname=scotchbox"

<Directory /var/www/public/web/>
    AuthName "You Must Login"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider dbd
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = %s"
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

The Auth pop comes up and i enter details which i have in the DB but then i get redirected to a Server Error 500: The error in the logs is:

```
[Thu Jul 07 11:59:21.675628 2016] [dbd:error] [pid 2183] (20014)Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to mysql: Access denied for user 'vagrant'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
[Thu Jul 07 11:59:21.675685 2016] [dbd:error] [pid 2183] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise
[Thu Jul 07 11:59:21.675709 2016] [authn_dbd:error] [pid 2183] [client 192.168.33.1:62383] AH01653: Failed to acquire database connection to look up user 'tom', referer: https://toran.modulemarket.dev/
```

So apparently the system can't connect to the DB, but im not sure why?! I can log in using the same mysql user vagrant/password and ive tried the root user, but to no avail.

Anyone know why I might not be able to connect to the database via DPD after following the guide above?

Thanks